# Data Annotation with Url not working

Tags: data-annotations

I used Url data Annotation in MVC as follow:

```
[Url]
[DisplayName("ULink")]
public string ULink { get; set; }
```

But some times it does not even allow the code with proper url ; it fails in ModelState.IsValid in the server side giving the following error message.

The Link to ULink field is not a valid fully-qualified http, https, or ftp URL.
Please Suggest

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that the URL must be fully-qualified.

I.E. It's missing the HTTP/HTTPS/FTP protocol.

EX: https://www.google.com, not www.google.com.